# django How to execute a function asynchronously i.e, handover a task to a sub process and return response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am using django 2.0 and python 3.6.

The user registration includes sending of a verification mail. And this mail sending process is taking longer and the user is kept waiting.

What I need?: If the user registration form is valid, mailing details are sent to another task handler and regardless of whether the mail is sent or not, the function must resume and return a response.

```
def new_user_registration(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        send_verification_mail(user) #<= taking more time.
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html')
```

i.e, the `send_verification_mail` must be called asynchronously. How to achieve it?

**Note:** I am new to django and python.

Comment: You may want to check out the celery library. It functions as a task manager to help long-running tasks keep from blocking other requests. It's commonly used with django and flask (can't link because of a network issue getting to their homepage)

Comment: Check out [Django's async support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/async/)

Comment: [question] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390314/how-to-call-asynchronous-function-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time you will use a [task queue](https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html) for this.

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) has been around for a long time and it is well known and documented, but recently I'm moving all my stuff to [TaskTiger](https://github.com/closeio/tasktiger)