# how to return 200OK before the function is completed

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, http, vk

I write a bot for Vkontakte on **Django(2.2.4)**, with the vk_api library

Some of the **functions are quite long (performed in 5-7 seconds)**. But Vkontakte requires the **server to respond no longer than 3 seconds**. If the response is delayed, the request is sent again, and the bot starts sending the same message many times after a while. (I Use The Callback Api)

**I will describe my problem briefly**

- **my function runs for more than 6 seconds**
- **the 200OK response must be sent in less than 3 seconds**

Is it possible to solve this problem without major changes in the code?

```
# views.py
@csrf_exempt
def MainBotView(request):
    # i need something like return HttpResponse('ok') here

    ... my slow code ...

    return HttpResponse('ok') # but I don't need it at the end
```

(I use pythonanywhere and Celery perhaps does not work there)

Should I use threading? How?

Comment: put your slow code in a thread , start , return and deal with thread

Comment: shouldnt that be a `202 Accepted`, not a 200?  </pedantic>

Comment: Spawning threads in WSGI web applications is not safe. The WSGI server might dispose whole processes with all its threads. You should store the request and use a background processing outside of the web application. Celery is a service that could be helpful.

Comment: Vkontakte requires a response with the code 200 and " OK"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790935/django-how-to-execute-a-function-asynchronously-i-e-handover-a-task-to-a-sub-pr

Comment: There is a help page on the PythonAnywhere help pages on how to do long-running tasks outside of the web app. Search for "async" in the help pages.