# How to call asynchronous function in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-3.0

The following doesn't execute `foo` and gives
`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited`

```
# urls.py

async def foo(data):
    # process data ...

@api_view(['POST'])
def endpoint(request):
    data = request.data.get('data')
    
    # How to call foo here?
    foo(data)

    return Response({})
```

Comment: `await foo(data)` ?

Comment: `await foo(data)` gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Your view function must be defined with `async` keyword

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a way to do it.

Create another file `bar.py` in the same directory as `urls.py`.

```
# bar.py

def foo(data):
    // process data
```

```
# urls.py

from multiprocessing import Process
from .bar import foo

@api_view(['POST'])
def endpoint(request):
    data = request.data.get('data')

    p = Process(target=foo, args=(data,))
    p.start()

    return Response({})
```

Comment: Tried this with `data` being a form and `foo` being a function to process that form (or more correct; changing some values depending of the value in the form). That didnt work...

Comment: yes, this worked! it's non blocking.

Answer (score 15):

Django is an synchronous language but it supports Async behavior.
Sharing the code snippet which may help.

```
    import asyncio
    from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

    def get_details(tag):
        response = another_sync_function()

        # Creating another thread to execute function
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        async_result = loop.run_until_complete(remove_tags(response, tag))
        loop.close()

    # Async function 
    async def remove_tags(response, tag_id):
        // do something here

        # calling another function only for executing database queries
        await tag_query(response, tag_id)

   @database_sync_to_async
   def tag_query(response, tag_id):
        Mymodel.objects.get(all_tag_id=tag_id).delete()
```

This way i called async function in synchronous function.

[Reference for database sync to async decorator](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html#database-sync-to-async)

Comment: How to do this on **class based view**?

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* await foo in this context. Seeing that Django is mainly a *synchronous* library, it doesn't interact well with asynchronous code. The best advice I can give it to try avoid using an asynchronous function here, or perhaps use another method of concurrency (ie threading or multiprocessing).

**Note:** there is a great answer given about Django's synchronous nature that can be found here: [Django is synchronous or asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548089/django-is-synchronous-or-asynchronous#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Django%20itself%20is%20synchronous.,intended%20for%20web%20sockets%20%2F%20etc).

Comment: Django 3.X support async

Comment: How do you have other methods of concurrency without asynchronicity?  What benefit would you be hoping to gain?